# How to set-up a /var/www/private folder?

Tags: apache2

I would like to change my apache2 setup on Debian in such way that only the files from:
/var/www/public/ would become the root of the website
/var/www/private/ not accessible from website, but accessible for the filesystem

currently the root of the site is /var/www/

example.com -> should redirect to -> /var/www/public/
example.com/private/ -> would redirect to -> /var/www/public/private/

a script on the filesystem in public should be able to contact /var/www/private/

Comment: When you say "accessible for scripts of public only", do you mean through the filesystem (like *include('../private');* or do you mean through links (like http://your-site/private/something_private.jpg )?

Comment: accessible for the filesystem only, for inclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change DocumentRoot to that path

Comment: I've changed the document root to /var/www/public/, but now the php scripts under /var/www/private/ won't execute anymore, they are handled as plain text